# Tracking down odd behavior right after opening Vim and using fuzzy finder

Tags: plugin-fzf

When I open Vim for the first time and go to search using `ctrl+p` **fzf** then start typing my search it gets prepended with the following text:

```
12;4$y
```

This means if I have typed `searching` it will become `12;4$ysearching`.  This only happens when I first open Vim and hit the key sequence to start the **fzf** finder before Vim has fully loaded.  I'm wanting to track down where in the startup process this is happening.

How can I track this oddity down?  [My .vimrc dot_files](https://github.com/shadoath/dot_files/blob/master/.vimrc)

Comment: How much time does you vim need to startup? Test it with `vim --startuptime vtime.log` ?

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/10604

Comment: @dedowsdi Last line is 405.889  000.001: --- VIM STARTED ---  I take that to mean it took .405 seconds to start. Which means I have to trigger fzf in the first half-second to get this oddity to show up.

Comment: @Shadoath  IMO 0.405 second is a bit slow, you might want to take a closer look at `vtime.log` and find out what's dragging you down. My point is that if you can reduce startup time to 0.2 second, your problem should vanish away most of time. If you really want to know why , you can follow above link to debug your vimrc.

Comment: I would agree, a faster startup would be great. The line that takes the longest is `365.514  194.023: reading viminfo`  Is this for my .vimrc file?

Comment: @Shadoath My `reading viminfo` took `000.435`, i guess something is wrong with your `'viminfo'` option.

Comment: @Shadoath You can open your `viminfo` file and check the content, it must be really   
 really big.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to some very helpful comments by @dedowsdi I have discovered some more about the vast world that is Vim.

1. You can test startup load time by running `vim --startuptime vtime.log` and inspecting the log file.
2. The main problem was due to my `viminfo` file being 22k lines after the updates below it is only 2.5k.
3. Updating my `.vimrc` options changed the load time of my `viminfo` to 008.324, more than 42x faster.

Current configuration inside my .vimrc file:

```
set history    =501
set viminfo    ='100,:100,@100,s10,\"100,h,n$v/files/info/viminfo
```

This took my load time from ~.4 a second to ~.2 second. The rest of this time is mostly plugins.

Extra notes:

- [Deleting Vim history](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/204693/157956)
- [Understanding what `set viminfo` options are on 7.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2816719/clear-certain-criteria-from-viminfo-file)
- [Docs on viminfo settings for 8.1](https://vim-jp.org/vimdoc-en/options.html#'viminfo')

Again thank you @dedowsdi for getting me going on tracking this all down.
**Edited for current config**

Comment: You are welcome. `undolevels` is not stored in `viminfo`, `501` might be too small if you work on a file for a whole day. `<` is the same as `"` .

Comment: And I continue to learn. Thank you again!